# How to set the spawn point to the overworld in minecraft 1.20?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a minecraft 1.20 world I set the spawn point to the end, and I tried to re-set it to the overworld by going to the overworld with the command

```
/execute as @p in minecraft:overworld run teleport 251 64 -160
```

and then use the command

```
/setworldspawn ~ ~ ~
```

But when I die I respawn back in the nether. But can I reset the spawn point to the overworld again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely situation you're in is that you have set a spawnpoint for yourself. Even if you set the world spawn in the nether or the end you will respawn in the overworld.

To check if you have a spawnpoint set you can use the command:

```
data get entity @s
```

Then look at the end of your chat to find `SpawnX`, `SpawnY` & `SpawnZ` they will have your spawnpoint coordinates.

If you have set your spawn point with a bed or anchor, you can reset your spawnpoint by destroying the bed or anchor and then run `/kill` or any other way. If you used the `spawnpoint` command you have to use a bed or anchor first. You'll get the message `"You have no home bed or charged respawn anchor, or it was obstructed"`. Then you can check for the spawn data again.

You can run this command so you don't need to look through the chat:

```
/data get entity @s SpawnX
```

This will give only the x coordinate, if you get a number you have a spawn but if you get the message: `"Found no elements matching SpawnX"` then you will spawn at the world spawn.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set the spawn for yourself in the nether. You can use /clearspawnpoint to remove a spawn point in the Nether. If you clear spawn then use /spawnpoint then put in the cords and dimension it should set your spawn to the overworld.